# Accessing username / committer's email from Codebuild build pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

As part of my AWS Codebuild pipeline, I am sending a Slack notification that includes the commit ID, which I obtain from the environment variable `CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION` as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

This is good, but I also want to access the name or email of the person who made the commit.

How can I possibly obtain that in the same way as I obtain the `CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeBuild webhook-triggered builds include the `.git` metadata. You should be able to retrieve this using the Git CLI, e.g.,:

```sh
git log -1 --format="%an <%ae>"
```

Which gives something like:

```
John Doe <jdoe@example.com>
```

The `aws/codebuild/standard` Docker image comes with Git pre-installed.

Comment: it's not working when I generate a Pull request

Comment: [Container] 2022/07/08 18:17:46 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: git log -1 --format="%an <%ae>". Reason: exit status 128